# customize tkinter menu while menu is open

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, menu, tkinter-menu

I want to have less popular menu items fade in gradually from white to black.  Is there any way to have the colors update while the menu is still open?  I've experimented with postcommand and threads:

```
def update():
    def color(c):
        animal_menu.config(fg=c)
        root.update()
        print c
    def adapt():
        color('white')
        root.after(100, color('#6E6E6E'))
        root.after(100, color('black'))
##  adapt() ##attempt no.1
##  thread.start_new_thread(adapt, ())  ##attempt no.2

root = Tk()
menubutton = Menubutton(root, text="Animals")
animal_menu = Menu(menubutton, tearoff=0, postcommand=update)
animal_menu.add_command(label="Lion", command=print_time)
animal_menu.add_command(label="Tiger", command=print_time)
animal_menu.add_command(label="Bear", command=print_time)
menubutton.menu = animal_menu
menubutton["menu"]  =  menubutton.menu
menubutton.pack()
root.config()
root.mainloop()
```

So far, the first attempt runs completely before the menu appears (which makes sense as postcommand is called before posting the menu), and the second attempt runs only when the menu is not open (which I don't understand) as evidenced by the print statements.

Could anybody give me a pointer on how to make the color properly dynamically change to have the items fade in while the menu is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with the `after` method in the callback:

```
def update():
    def color(c):
        animal_menu.config(fg=c)
        root.update()
        print c
    def adapt():
        color('white')
        root.after(100, color('#6E6E6E'))
        root.after(100, color('black'))
    adapt() ##attempt no.1
```

First, if you're passing arguments to the function being called in the after, you have to use a lambda expression or just split them by a comma:

```
root.after(100, color, 'black')
```

Otherwise, the parenthesis will make that function be evaluated first.

Second, `after` doesn't work with the typical control flow you're probably used to--it's not evaluated one, then the next--you're setting both after calls to be evaluated after 100ms, so that's what's going to happen.

Here's a working example of a fadein callback:

```
from Tkinter import *

def fadein(color):
    if color < 111111:
        animal_menu.config(fg='#000000')
    else:
        print color
        animal_menu.config(fg='#' + str(color))
        root.after(100, fadein, color - 111111)

root = Tk()
menubutton = Menubutton(root, text="Animals")
animal_menu = Menu(menubutton, tearoff=0, postcommand=lambda: fadein(999999))
animal_menu.add_command(label="Lion")
animal_menu.add_command(label="Tiger")
animal_menu.add_command(label="Bear")
menubutton.menu = animal_menu
menubutton["menu"]  =  menubutton.menu
menubutton.pack()
root.config()
root.mainloop()
```

Note the lambda expression, in `postcommand`, which is needed to pass the argument to `fadein()`.

More info: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method

Comment: Ah, I understand about the `after` call - thanks!  I tried the example, though, and for me the `after` calls still didn't begin until the menu had been closed, so I can't see the fade in (except as evidenced by print statements I put in, which appear after the menu is unposted).  Are you able to see it happening in the open menu?

Comment: See my edit for the full working code for me. It works, but it flickers--and it doesn't start at FFFFFF (white), but 999999 (light gray), so the change isn't as apparent.

Comment: Interesting - I copied your code exactly and ran that on my machine (Mac OS 10.6, python 2.7 for compatibility), and saw the same behavior of not fading until after the menu closed.  Out of curiosity, I tried it in my Windows 7 VM which has python 3.4, and it looks lovely!  I can specify the environment reqs, so this solves my problem -- thanks so much!